# placing canvas circles in circular manner without overlapping

Tags: javascript

I have to draw concept map of circles with same radius once it is clicked it should show its children and those children should not overlap each other. I am able to divide entire circular position with `Math.PI*2/required_length_of_children`. and taking positions with

```
 var new_left=Math.round(origin.x+radius*Math.cos(angle));
 var new_top=Math.round(origin.y+radius*Math.sin(angle));
```

Now my problem is how to find out the angle which has available space and draw those. basically looking for hyperbolic tree manner arrangement of circles.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Sounds more like a math question.

Comment: I have got an answer for this. we can take a angle of dissection from root. if root has three children we have to divide initially by 3 that gives us 120 degrees each. calculate the angle of children line which it has come and use 120 degrees to place its children. as we divide and get no.of degrees from each children we have increase line length and then place it.

Comment: @suresh If you have a working answer, please consider adding an answer to the question.  Maybe others face a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, when a circle sits with its center on the edge of another circle, the triangle between the two centers and one intersection point has all its edges known: R, R, and r (where R is the large radius, and r is the small one).  We can use some math to find the angle at the center of the big circle for this:

https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-sss-triangles.html

We can then double that so that the angle accounts for the entire width of the small circle on the edge, and the formula ends up looking like this: `2*Math.acos(1 - (r**2)/(2*R**2))`

Now to make sure this math is right, we can draw on a canvas to ensure that circles placed with this angle don't overlap:

```
function testShape(middleX, middleY, R, r, n) {
  var i, angle = 0;
  var inc = 2*Math.acos(1 - (r**2)/(2*R**2));

  circle(middleX, middleY, "blue", R);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    circle(middleX+Math.cos(angle)*R, middleY+Math.sin(angle)*R, "red", r);
    angle += inc;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/snydergd/rh6jcf30/7/

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant answer. I just considered you didn't convert the degree to radian properly and as a result if someone changes the starting angle to something like 90, it won't locate the first circle accurately.

So, this is the updated one, for who need it:
https://jsfiddle.net/afshindev/7oLrgm9h/16/